# Firefox Extension working locally, but not on another computer

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a simple Firefox extension (taken from the docs), and when I run the extension on my the machine I built it on, everything works just as planned. But the moment I upload the file to Dropbox, download it onto another computer, and install it absolutely nothing happens. Both Fire Fox browsers are version 42.0, on Windows 7

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
             ' "<h1>Does this work?!</h1>";'
});
```

Comment: Any errors on the browser console?

Comment: Absolutely none. @CViejo

Comment: how do u run on local machine as well as other machine?

Comment: By building the .xpi @Nandu

Comment: is this a test add-on,if yes can u upload the package to github. I can try it on my machine

Comment: Thanks for the offer @Nandu but I've already had three other people test it. Same results. This code was right off the doc site so I have no idea why I wouldn't be compatible (even though all of us had the same FF version except for one)

Comment: @Nandu Is there any signing thing with Firefox? Like where you can only test plugins locally, then you must get em signed?

Comment: in FF , type about:config. check for xpinstall.signatures.required. This value must be false

Comment: if the value is "true" change it to "false" and retry

Comment: Did you do `jpm xpi` then trying to install that xpi elsewhere?

Comment: @Nandu I'll ask my friends to check so once they're up.

Comment: @Noitidart yup. Ran jpm xpi, tested on my own Firefox, then one on a RDP, then two of my friends tested. Only worked on my own FF.

Comment: @Nandu on the remote desktop, I checked and that option is set to false. Although it doesn't work.

Comment: if you have xpi, why do u do "jpm xpi". Can you try installing the add-on in FF on your machine?

Comment: jpm xpi generated the .xpi file. That's why I ran it. And I've already explained I have

Comment: Are you try to delete the appData on the other computer?

Comment: What are you even saying @ChristosPapoulas ? No one has brought up appData at all.

Comment: I was having the same issue with you. The extensions was working fine in my PC and not working at all in the other PC. After deleting the AppData of Firefox folder in the other PC, everything works